# Can i register a new subdomain of an organization

Tags: dns, subdomain

Can I create a sub-domain? suppose there is an organization and they have a domain organization.com  can I register a domain named anything.organization.com please reply fast?

Comment: "please reply fast?" Why exactly? Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest . And your question is offtopic here as not releated to programming at all. Wikipedia has good articles on both DNS and domain name registration, you may want to start reading those and "fast" to have a better understanding of things.

Comment: Subdomains do NOT require additional registration. 
When you use domain organization.com, you're actually telling all DNS providers around the world that you, the owner of organization.com, would like visitors to organization.com to visit a defined IP Address using an A record, CNAME, or AAAA record.
You can do exactly the same by pointing your subdomain DNS to another IPV4(A Record) or another domain/subdomain (CNAME record) or an IPV6 (AAAA record).

Answer (score 0):

If you own the domain, then yes, you can easily register a subdomain and there are many many tutorials online that explain how to do this.

If, however, you're part of an organization that owns the top-level domain, then you'll likely have to speak to whoever is "in charge of" that domain if you want a custom subdomain made for your purposes.

In general, the larger the organization, the slimmer your chances are of getting this approved...